# How to accept yes from script "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"

Tags: linux, ssh

I have tried

```
echo yes | ssh myserver@13.4.2.1
yes | ssh myserver@13.4.2.1
ssh -y myserver@13.4.2.1
```

none of which appear to work?

#### EDIT #1

Part of my problem was I thought every command after the `ssh` command was a remote command when the commands were in fact local. I guess remote commands have to be declared in a string which is passed to the ssh command as an argument e.g.

```
$ ssh myserver@13.4.2.1 'remote command'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't care to authenticate the hosts via SSH and either blindly accept the keys from servers or ignore them, better to just ignore them.

```
$ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<host>
```

Keep in mind that you're arm tying SSH's ability to protect you but this is the more appropriate way to use the tools as they're intended vs. forcing them through external means.

Comment: It works better without `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`

Answer (score 29):

This is by design.  `ssh`'s host verification and authentication interactions *deliberately* do not accept input from pipes.  However, you can if you are confident in your host keys do:

```
ssh-keyscan host.example.com >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh host.example.com
```

Comment: so for hose name i can just use <user-name>@<ip-address> right?

Comment: Well, `user@hostname` is not a hostname.  It's a username _at_ a hostname.  But you can use that syntax to specify a remote user on a remote host, yes.